# Using ansible ignore_errors in a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm using ansible 2.4.0 and try to use `ignore_errors` depending on check mode and `with_items` in combination.
According to the [docs about check_mode](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_checkmode.html#information-about-check-mode-in-variables) you can define ignore_errors based on if ansible is running in check mode or not. Without the `with_items` directive this works good, but with both elements a fail is always ignored.

Working example without `with_items`:

```
# test_i.yml
- name: test without array and with ignore
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - fail: msg="I fail, but ignored in check mode"
      ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"

    - debug: msg="Reachable only in check mode"
```

Not working example:

```
# test_ai.yml
- name: test with array and with ignore
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - fail: msg="I am always skipped"
      ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"
      with_items: [ 1, 2 ]

    - debug: msg="Always reached"
```

Execute with and results:

```
ansible-playbook test_i.yml --check
# ok=2, failed=0, but fail-task printed in red
ansible-playbook test_i.yml
# ok=0, failed=1, canceled after fail task
ansible-playbook test_ai.yml --check
# ok=2, failed=0, but fail-task items printed in red
ansible-playbook test_ai.yml
# ok=2, failed=0, same as with check
```

If the ignore_errors is removed or commented out, the task fails as desired, but then it does in check mode, too. It works even if `check_mode` is defined as false - but that wouldn't make any sense, would it.

Am I missing something or might this be a bug?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily trust `fail` module to behave in the same way as another action module failing. What is your objective? You want a general answer/solution, or specifically for `fail`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. I've filed an issue [31831](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31831) with explanation.

Comment: Thanks for investigating and filing the issue.